# How do I enable Index Management in 1.13.1?

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade, ee-1.13

In the [Upgrading to and Verifying Magento Community Edition 1.8 and Enterprise Edition 1.13 - Part 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading) document, step 3.h reads:

> Set all indexers to update when scheduled (**System** > **Configuration** > ADVANCED > **Index Management**, **Update when scheduled**.

That's awesome, but I don't have Index Management in my ADVANCED menu. What's the missing step to enable this?

[image: Missing Index Management]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Index Management tab would normally show up at the bottom of the list under Advanced like so. As for why it is not showing up…the only reason this would happen is if the core of Magento has not been upgraded properly or the core been modified. There are no settings you need for this to turn up. Clearing your cache may help, if you haven't already done so since finishing the upgrade; but your best bet is going to be making certain you have every last file from EE 1.13.1.0 core in your codebase untouched.

[image]:

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. In looking through table core_resource, I see that the upgrade installs did not actually fire off. Everything is still set to version 1.6, 1.11 or 1.12 -- nothing is at 1.13. Admin is showing version 1.13.1.0 but missing the new 1.13 functionality... Back to ground zero.

Comment: What the admin displays comes straight off of the Mage god class. Or i.e. it's static and not based on what's in core_resource.

Comment: Too long to post here, but I've put up a SQL dump of the core_resource table of a mostly clean 1.13.1.0 install I have for you to compare against here: https://gist.github.com/davidalger/ce1572df666c5485daf2

Comment: Thank you. I will use these module versions as a guide to test the installation.

Comment: Thanks again. The issue was (embarrassingly) that I had failed to copy over app/etc/modules, so none of the new modules were installing. We keep app/etc in a separate repository than the Magento core files. I figured this out thanks to your dump of core_resource. Now I also see `enterprise_cataloginventory_setup 1.13.0.0, enterprise_catalogsearch_setup 1.13.0.0, enterprise_catalog_setup 1.13.0.9, enterprise_index_setup 1.13.0.1`